# Prove that for all real numbers $a$ and $b$, $|a| ≤ b$ iff $-b ≤ a ≤ b$

Tags: inequality, solution-verification

The problem is from exercise 12 of chapter 3.5 of Velleman's How To Prove It.
For the (---->) direction, I realise we are supposed to break the proof into two cases.
So, suppose $$|a|≤ b $$ Case 1:   $a=|a| $ which implies $a≤b.\;$ Now suppose $-b>a,\;$which implies $-a>b,\;$ but we know that $a≤b,\;$ so $-b>a\;$ is a contradiction. Therefore, $-b≤a.\;$Since we now know that $a≤b\;$ and $-b≤a,\;$we can conclude that $-b ≤ a ≤ b.$

Case 2: $-a=|a|,\;$which implies  $-a≤b,\;$which is equivalent to $-b≤a.$

This is where I'm stuck at. From the assumption of case 2, we have deduced that $-b≤a. \;$ But I don't know how to prove that $a≤b\;$ to reach the stated goal of $-b ≤ a ≤ b \:$ for this case. Assuming $a ≤ b \;$ is false (that is, assuming $a>b$) and trying to reach a contradiction doesn't seem to work.

I'm sure the solution is simple but I've spent 2 hours on this with no luck. ;
Thank you for your time.

EDIT: I should have clarified that since the text is about proof strategies, the author intended the reader to use proof by cases in this section of the book to get a better grasp of that particular strategy. Even so, thank you all so much for all the different ways of approaching the proof that you suggested! I've learned new things today!

For case 2, I ended up using the fact that $a<0\,$ to prove that $a≤b. \,$ That is, since $a<0\,$ iff $-a>0,\,$ and since $b≥-a,\,$ then $b>0.\,$ Thus we have $a<0<b,\,$ which implies $a≤b.\,$
Therefore, we can conclude that $-b ≤ a ≤ b.$

Comment: **Hint :** $a=|a|$ means that $a$ is non-negative, and $a=-|a|$ means that $a$ is non-positive. (and $|a|  \leq b$ implies that $b$ is non-negative !)

Comment: Another way to make @TheSilverDoe's point:  It would be better to set up the cases as Case 1:  $a \ge 0$, Case 2:  $a < 0$.  Then in case 1 you will have $|a| = a$ and in case 2 you will have $|a| = -a$, as in your proof, but in each case you will have an additional piece of information:  $a \ge 0$ in case 1, and $a < 0$ in case 2.

Comment: Note that several answers below propose tricks you can use to avoid reasoning by cases.  While these tricks aren't wrong, they miss the point of the exercise.  This is an exercise in a section of the book that addresses proof by cases.  The point of the exercise is to practice proof by cases, not to learn a fact about absolute values.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe   Why $b$ is non-negative? See please better the question. $b$ is a real number and we need to prove our statement for any reals $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Not sure what edition you have, but this is exercise 13, not 12 in the third edition

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I said that $|a| \leq b$ implies that $b$ is non-negative. I think you agree...

Comment: @TheSilverDoe  The statement $|a|\leq b\Rightarrow b\geq0$ is true for any real value of  $b$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg This is exactly what I said ! I don't understand what you don't understand...

Comment: @TheSilverDoe thank you!

Comment: @DanVelleman Thank you so much! I think I've figured it out by not skipping the $a≥0\,$ and $a<0\,$ steps. Also, I just want to say that your book has quickly become my favourite math text of all time! It's genuinely a joy to read and work through (I've never been compelled to complete all exercises in a textbook before). I'm only in chapter 3 at the moment as you can see, but it has already helped me immensely!

Comment: @CSquared I have the 2nd edition of the book because I purchased it in 2018. I didn't even know there was a new edition until you mentioned it just now (or that it has a whole new chapter on number theory!)

Comment: @QuickBenRush yea i have been using it a lot. it really helped.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this maximum properties $\quad\begin{cases}\max(x,y)+z=\max(x+z,y+z)\\\max(u,v)\le w\iff (u\le w)\text{ and }(v\le w)\end{cases}$

$|a|=\max(a,-a)\le b\iff \max(a,-a)-b\le 0\iff \max(a-b,-a-b)\le 0 \iff\begin{cases}a-b\le 0\\-a-b\le 0\end{cases}\iff \begin{cases}a\le b\\-b\le a\end{cases}\iff -b\le a\le b$

This way of proceeding somehow 'hides' the multiple cases discussion.

Comment: I found a solution using the cases approach but this is a super interesting way to approach it (I'm adding it to my toolbag hahah), thank you for the new perspective!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Take the concrete case $\left|-2\right| \le 4$. You're stuck proving that $-2 \le 4$. Of course, it's true; how do you know that it's true? Can you generalise this reasoning?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Why make things more complex than they are?
As $|a|\le b$ implies $b$ is nonnegative, we have
$$|a|\le b\iff |a|^2=a^2\le b^2,$$
so it comes down to an inequality *without* absolute values.

Comment: Do you mean $|a| \le b$?

Comment: @martycohen: Yes, of course. I definitely should reread what I post… Thank you for pointing it!

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: Of course, if $b<0$, two false statements are always logically equivalent, but I think considering this case is absurd.

Comment: @Bernard  The word absurd it's an emotion only. I think, we need to prove our statement in this case in any case.  I agree, it's obvious, but we need to say it.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: What goes without saying is better said? ;o)

Comment: @Bernard I'll explain why it's very  important. If we need to solve for example $|x|\leq2x-1$ we don't need to write $2x-1\geq0$, but $-2x+1\leq x\leq 2x-1$ only,  which gives $x\geq1.$

Comment: But we nevertheless have to solve two  inequalities, one of them being implied by the other. What's the difference with writing the necessary condition $x\ge \frac12$ and solving only the r.h.s. inequality?

Comment: @Bernard What about the following? $|x|\leq x^3−x+1$. I hope now it's clear, why it's so important.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: You're right. I only imagined  quite simple examples (examples for a nursery school, as used to say one of my teachers).

Answer (score 0):

For Case $2$:

If $-a=|a|$ and we know that $|a|\geq 0$, then we must have $a\leq 0$.

We are given $0\leq -a=|a|\leq b$ so $0\leq b$.

By transitivity, $a\leq 0\leq b\Longrightarrow a\leq b$.

Working with the given, we have $-a\leq b$, so when we multiply both sides by $-1$, we obtain $-b\leq a$.

By transitivity, we obtain $$-b\leq a\leq b$$

Answer (score -3):

I think the following reasoning is shorter.

For $b\geq0$ it's obvious by the definition of the absolute value:

$|a|$ it's a distance between the point, which is corresponded to $a$ on the number axis, and the origin, which gives immediately: $$|a|\leq b\Leftrightarrow -b\leq a\leq b$$

But for $b<0$ the statement $$|a|\leq b\Leftrightarrow -b\leq a\leq b$$ is also obvious and we are done!